# How to draw a free hand polygon by one finger touch on top of mkmapview?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I would like to draw a free hand polygon with one finger on top of a Mkmapview.  I know how to draw a free hand polygon on a UIView and I know how to bring up a mkmapview.

I don't know if I can use the overlay function because I need to draw the polygon when my finger moved.  I assume that this involves multitouch event and drawRect but i can not make it work when I put them together.

Thanks in advance if someone can help.